# Android SecurityException : fused location provider requires [...] permission

Tags: android, exception, android-location, android-permissions

I encountered crashs on my apps with permissions.
I've an activity with GoogleMap and location, and it's worked perfectly... since some users started to crash, and I can't understand why exactly..
It's happened both in Android 6.0 & 4.1.2.
I've reproduced it on Android 5.1.1 by removing permissions with a tiers-apps, but can't understand why it's happening for common-user, especially for Android 4.

This is where the app crash :

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, this, null);
```

Here are logs :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: "fused" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
```

I've try to test if permissions are granted with (for Marshmallow) :

```
(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

And (for earlier :)

```
(getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

But as expected it don't go in the conditions.
Of course, both ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION & ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION are correctly added in the Manifest, since there was no crashs before...

Any clues of what's the problem is ?

Comment: This is an open bug reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707). There seems to be no solution yet.